# how to make div 100% height relative to screen, if div has `top` property

Tags: html, css

My `div` block has a `top='70px'` property. When `div` has a scroll, his also moves down, and the end of the scroll is not visible.
I added the following properties to the div, but it did not help:

```
div {
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Example:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;  
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #222;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Section #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Section #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Section #3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page #3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page #4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page #5</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page #6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please share relevant code provided code is not enough for debugging

Comment: It seems that you expect the scrollbar to stay put while pushing said `div` downward using `top` *although i don't any position value*, as stated by yourself `When div has a scroll` the scroll belongs to said `div` the same `div` you pushed down, i don't expect your head to stay where it is if you were pushed down, now would you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `calc()` to subtract the div's `top` from the screens total height,
something like this

```css
div {
  top: 70px;
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}
```